# структура pe файла

Tags: pe

Здравствуйте, не поможете мне в кое-чем разобраться ? Я, для обогащения своих знаний, начал изучать структуру pe файла, после просмотра общей схемы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и немного почитав теории, у меня закралась мысля, а что, если заменить секции одного ехе на чужой ехе (секции, что идут после хедеров), если я правильно понял, то понять, откуда начинается text section не особо сложно. И главный вопрос : Будет ли работать ехе ?
получается, что сами хедеры (иконки, заголовки, сигнатуры, дата и тп) остаются прежними, а вот сам код другой
я, конечно, сомневаюсь, что такое будет работать, но в теории, почему бы и нет ?
что вы думаете по этому поводу ?

Comment: обычно все таки меняют ресурсы  (иконки и т.п.), в готовом exe. Но конечно никто не мешает составлять exe из любых частей, которые вам придут в голову, главное что бы выполнимый код был выполним и все заголовки и прочие секции соответствовали формату

Comment: @Mike тобишь, если я заменю у ехе только раздел Sections на взяв такой же с другого ехе, то все будет работать ? кхм, а можно ли в раздел Sections закинь сразу два ехе ? запустятся сразу оба ?(тут понимаю, что шанс мал, но спросить стоит)

Comment: В заголовке еще определена точка входа и она должна разумеется верно указывать на первую выполняемую инструкцию из сегмента кода  . И так же если код обращается к каким то данным из сегментов данных все ссылки должны быть корректны, а это значит что заменить например только сегмент кода, не меняя сегментов данных, нельзя.

Comment: Чтобы все работало нужно аккуратно заменить секции, прописать их начала, размеры, атрибуты в таблице секций, и прописать точку входа (Entry Point) в заголовке. Теоретически можно в один экзешник запихнуть два (если виртуальные адреса секций не пересекаются), но выполняться будет только тот код, адрес которого (точка входа) прописан в заголовке.

Comment: В общем, работать не будет. Потому что съедут импорты, смещения и так далее. Ну и не совсем понятно что именно вы хотите менять ;-)

Comment: спасибо. Не подскажите, инфа о ехе (иконка,дополнительная инфа( создатель и тп) ) находится в секции data ? , которая самая последняя

Comment: @Lolidze Она находится в директории ресурсов (которых у вас на картинке нет), которая может быть и отдельной секцией (например .rsrc). Есть альтернативная секциям разбивка файла на директории.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов можно ли нахождение этой секции программно вычислить ?  Если Скопировать эту секуцию и вставить в другой ехе будет ли работать ? или нужно подправлять что-то ?

Comment: @Lolidze да легко. Между Optional Header и Section Headers (а на самом деле в первом) есть таблица из структур IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY, каждая из которых описывает директорию. Третья директория - директория ресурсов. Вот вы ее и нашли, считайте. Насчет замены - сложный вопрос. Если программа при работе к ним не обращается - может и будет работать после пересадки... Только секции и директории придется править.

Comment: Скачайте Exescope.exe c сети, он наглядно разшифровует заголовки.

Comment: Или HIEW, он и сразу редактировать их может, и вообще da really cewl to0l

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь, попробую разобраться, как появятся вопросы я напишу сюда, вы не против ?)